EF Core with PostgreSQL 16 - Create a Unique Index with `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` for a GUID
I have one property in an entity that is the type of Guid it's unique but nullable.
Since null GUID is equal to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, the PostgreSQL disallows me from inserting a second record where the Guid is null (all zeroes) as it violates the index constraint.
Because of this I've tried to configure NULLS NOT DISTINCT by adding AreNullsDistinct(false) to the index.
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public required Guid Id { get; set; }
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid AdObjectId { get; set; } // Link employee back to identity in AD, can be null as some employee might not present in the AD
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasIndex(e => e.AdObjectId).IsUnique().AreNullsDistinct(false);
    }
}

However, when I inspect the DDL, the NULLS NOT DISTINCT are absent from the index:
create table "Employee"
(
    "Id"         uuid                           not null
        constraint "PK_Employee" primary key,
    "FirstName"  text                           not null,
    "LastName"   text                           not null,
    "AdObjectId" uuid                           not null
);

create unique index "IX_Employee_AdObjectId"
    on "Employee" ("AdObjectId");

Below is the migration (only the index creation part) for reference:
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Employee_AdObjectId",
    table: "Employee",
    column: "AdObjectId",
    unique: true)
    .Annotation("Npgsql:NullsDistinct", false);

I am wondering, do I miss any additional configuration for the NULLS NOT DISTINCT to be present on the index?
Environment details:

.NET Core 8
PostgreSQL 16
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 8.0.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design: 8.0.4
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL: 8.0.4


What makes you think null Guid is equal to all zeros (aka empty)?

@DavidG The default value for Guid in C# is all zeroes (same as Guid.Empty), I've also tested create/update with the EF Core multiple times, when the AdObjectId is absent from the entity, the end result in PostgreSQL is always all zeroes uuid

Yes, the default value for a non-nullable Guid is all zeroes, aka Guid.Empty, but the default value for a nullable Guid is null. And null does not equal Guild.Empty

You have a dictionary where each row must be unique.  The key is DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity  The key must be distinct in a dictionary.

@DavidG Thanks for pointing out, let me check how my code treats the value when the received Guid is null.

@jdweng The property with an issue is AdObjectId, does the DatabaseGenerated annotation in Id property also affect other indexes?

@phwt I recommend ignoring jdweng, his comments on this site are wildly inaccurate. For example, you don't have a dictionary here at all.

Here is the Npgsql document:

By default, when you create a unique index, PostgreSQL treats null values as distinct; this means that a unique index can contain multiple null values in a column. When creating an index, you can also instruct PostgreSQL that nulls should be treated as non-distinct; this causes a unique constraint violation to be raised if a column contains multiple null values.

Seems what you want is the default behaivor of npgsql and you shouldn't use AreNullsDistinct to suppress it!
I'd suggest to remove the AreNullsDistinct and create new migration but check the generated code before updating database.
The npgsql link: See

I forgot to mark Guid as nullable, changing it to public Guid? AdObjectId { get; set; } works! As you said, there is no need to use AreNullsDistinct and the not null is not present on the AdObjectId column now.
